# Javascript - Possible to check if an interval is already set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a div that is bouncing every 5 seconds using an interval.

When scrolling to the bottom of the page, this div fades out and the interval is cleared.

However, I think there is an issue with the interval being created multiple times and overlaps upon itself.

Is there a way to check if an interval is set, and if so clear it, and if not, to set it?

The reason I need to clear the interval is because the bounce effect of jquery causes the div to appear again even if it's hidden.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/ijuhok/4/

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you set the interval whenever it is scrolled. So if I scroll down, and then scroll down again you set it twice.

Just clear it before hand every time you set it and you should be ok.

http://jsbin.com/ijuhok/6

Answer (score 4):

You need to overwrite the existing interval so that you can clear it from everywhere: http://jsbin.com/ijuhok/5/.

```
$j("#more").fadeIn('slow',function(){
    ResInterval = window.setInterval(bounceMore, 5000);
    // no "var"
});
```

You can eliminate `$(document).ready` for `window` because it's always available.

Comment: Wow! You were so quick I can't even accept the answer for 6 more minutes. Perfect, thank you! - And thank you to everyone else for the quick and also perfect solutions - it was definitely due to redefining all the time with 'var'

Comment: OK There is something very strange happening, if you leave the site idle for a minute or so, the div seems to lose its positioning and moves to the top of the screen. Do you have any idea what is happening? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/396112/_IMG/_misc/setinterval-bounce.jpg (OS X 10.7.2, Chrome 15.0.874.106)

Comment: @waffl: I don't know why, but resetting the CSS properties that are set seems wo work: http://jsbin.com/ijuhok/7/.

Comment: Oh no, I hate to tell you but it's still having issues, so strange, have no idea why: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/396112/_IMG/_misc/Screen%20Shot%202011-11-01%20at%2010.59.47%20AM.png

Comment: @waffl: I fiddled around and this hack seems to solve it (on Chrome): http://jsbin.com/ijuhok/8/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're defining `ResInterval` in a local scope, because you've used `var`:

```
$j("#more").fadeIn('slow',function(){
   var ResInterval = window.setInterval('bounceMore()', 5000);
});
```

Remove the `var` prefix, and your code will work as expected: Currently, `ResInterval` is a local varibale of the callback function in `fadeIn`. When `var` is omitted, the interval will be assigned to the closest `ResInterval` declaration (using `var`).

Comment: Ah exactly - thank you for the explanation, especially bringing my attention to the scope of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I did this like below, My problem was solved. you should set the value like "false", when you clearTimeout the timer.

```
var timeer=false;
----
----
if(timeer==false)
{
  starttimer();  
}
-----
-----
function starttimer()
{
  timeer=setInterval(activefunction, 1000); 
}

function pausetimer()
{
  clearTimeout(timeer);
  timeer=false;
}
```