# setInterval function running indefinitely on two activations?

Tags: p5.js

I'm using setInterval in a simple sketch that generates a shape + text in random colors, rotation, and locations five times (using a counter). It activates on button press and works when the button is pressed once. However, when the button is pressed before the first five are down being drawn, the function repeats indefinitely. Would love tips on how to fix.

```
var canvas;
var interval; 
var counter = 0;
function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup () {
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0, 0);
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1')
    background('white');

    inp = createInput();
    inp.position(80, 150);
    inp.input(inputEvent);

    button = createButton('Go');
    button.position(85 + inp.width, 150);
    button.mousePressed(indefSomewhere);
}

function inputEvent() {
    console.log(this.value())
}

function goSomewhere() {
    const place = inp.value();
    // for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        push();
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        translate(random(width), random(height));
        rotate(random(2*PI));
        noStroke();
        beginShape();
        
        vertex(80, 50);
        vertex(300, 50);
        vertex(350, 95);
        vertex(300, 140);
        vertex(80, 140);
        scale(0.5);
        endShape(CLOSE);
        push();
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        text(place, 100, 124);
        pop();
        pop();
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        if(counter >= 5) {
            counter = 0;
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(counter);
        } else if(counter === 0 ) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    //   }
}

function indefSomewhere() {
    interval = setInterval(goSomewhere, 100);
}


function draw() {
    fill(0);
    beginShape();
    vertex(80, 50);
    vertex(300, 50);
    vertex(350, 95);
    vertex(300, 140);
    vertex(80, 140);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    fill(255);
    if(inp.value() != null) {
        textSize(32);
        text(inp.value(), 87.5, 125);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, I've added a clear interval to the indefSomewhere() function and it prevents the indefinite drawing of shapes. However double clicking doesn't activate the drawing twice. Is setInterval simply the wrong choice for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem comes when setInterval() is called while the interval is already set, I would make so that if the interval hasn't been set, it calls setInterval(), but if it has, it adds +5 to the limit of the counter.

This could be the code:

```
var canvas;
var interval;
var intervalSet;
var counter = 0;
var maxCounter;

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup () {
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0, 0);
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1')
    background('white');

    inp = createInput();
    inp.position(80, 150);
    inp.input(inputEvent);

    button = createButton('Go');
    button.position(85 + inp.width, 150);
    button.mousePressed(indefSomewhere);
}

function inputEvent() {
    console.log(this.value())
}

function goSomewhere() {
    const place = inp.value();
    // for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        push();
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        translate(random(width), random(height));
        rotate(random(2*PI));
        noStroke();
        beginShape();
        
        vertex(80, 50);
        vertex(300, 50);
        vertex(350, 95);
        vertex(300, 140);
        vertex(80, 140);
        scale(0.5);
        endShape(CLOSE);
        push();
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        text(place, 100, 124);
        pop();
        pop();
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        if(counter >= maxCounter) {
            counter = 0;
            intervalSet = false;
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(counter);
        } else if(counter === 0 ) {
            intervalSet = false;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    //   }
}

function indefSomewhere() {
  if(!intervalSet){
    maxCounter = 5;
    intervalSet = true;
    interval = setInterval(goSomewhere, 100);
  }else{
    maxCounter += 5;
  }
    
}


function draw() {
    fill(0);
    beginShape();
    vertex(80, 50);
    vertex(300, 50);
    vertex(350, 95);
    vertex(300, 140);
    vertex(80, 140);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    fill(255);
    if(inp.value() != null) {
        textSize(32);
        text(inp.value(), 87.5, 125);
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7956173/14131521) is a related question.